# PHP DateTime Update

Tags: php, oop, datetime

I'm using PHP > 5.3 and i have a question regarding DateTime:

First i'm not able to use:

```
$date   = new DateTime('2012-06-08 00:00:00');
$t = $date->createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2012-06-11 23:59:59');
```

I get the following error message:

> Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()

I can use other function in that class.

The second thing i'm puzzled about how to update the object initial date, or do i have to create a new object?

Comment: Which part of the error message is hard to understand for you in specific?

Comment: @hakre but that function should be available for php >= 5.3 which op claims to be using

Comment: @Jack: Did it ever came into your mind that stuff produced by humans (which includes questions here as well next to (my) comment) can contain errors? For that just in case, I ask before I answer. Because communications can be helpful to remove errors. Together we survive, alone we fail.

Comment: @hakre why sure, that's why i didn't add an answer myself :) maybe i just mixed up chat room and question comments =/

Comment: @hakre as jack said it should work in PHP > 5.3...! and i also tried calling it as static but it also gives the same error

Comment: Well, I still need to ask you: "Which part of the error message don't you understand?"

Comment: @hakre i obviously understand the error...just dont understand why is it happening since i can use other methods of this object and i made sure PHP > 5.3

Comment: @DannyValariola What does this output `var_dump(get_class_methods('DateTime'));`

Comment: @MikeB
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "format"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "modify"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "getTimezone"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "setTimezone"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "getOffset"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "setTime"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "setDate"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "setISODate"
}

Comment: I understand that it doesnt have this method...just dont understand why??
P.S - Thanks for the direction @MikeB

Comment: Anyone has any suggestion why i'm missing functions???

Comment: What does `echo __NAMESPACE__;` output? Place it after the line `$date   = new DateTime('2012-06-08 00:00:00');`.

Comment: hakre beat me to it! Also try this: `$a = (1 != 1) ?: 'default';` @MikeB `DateTime` has been available since php 5.2.

Comment: I think i solved it...guess i should have had another look at my environment.
when I executed the script in a browser it works!
Examining the run CLI in eclipse (DEBUG option) it was set to PHP 5.2...

Comment: Derp, forgot DateTime is 5.2 :(

Comment: No, if `__NAMESPACE__` is an undefined constant, you don't have PHP 5.3. If it is, it will actually provide *additional* info. Clever, right?

Comment: That's a leftover comment from earlier I didn't post: Okay, so you have clarified that that function does not exist with that object/class. But still you insist that you want to use the non-existent function because the manual has made you belief that there must be such a function? A rule of thumb here: *Trust the terrain, not the map.* which is saying: Accept what you face. Next part is look closer why that function does not exist there.

Comment: @hakre lolololol great saying...i knew it wasnt there - i needed help finding out why....?? I'll try the __NAMESPACE__  now

Comment: @hakre well...both:
    echo __NAMESPACE__;
    $a = (1 != 1) ? '1' : 'default';
worked but i still dont have access to that function i think it's an eclipse issue.. :(

Comment: You can configurate the PHP interpreter you want to use in ecplise. No idea about your configuration, but you just need to use a PHP 5.3 version. Install it on your system, help eclipse to find it and done.

Answer (score 6):

`createFromFormat` is a static method of `DateTime` so you would need to call it like:

```
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2012-06-11');
```

You can update the initial `$date` object by doing:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2012-06-11');
```

Comment: Ryan, the error is "undefined method", so probably it's not only because of static, right?

Comment: @Ryan this gives the save error..

Comment: @dnagirl can you give an example....not sure i follow?

Comment: @DannyValariola How about using `strtotime` then? Really weird how `createFromFormat` isn't working for you on php > 5.3

Comment: yeah I know i can use strtotime...used it before :)

Comment: I vote for a `phpinfo` dump :D

Comment: @dnagirl The error message he is getting has nothing to do with what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @Ryan from phpinfo:
Apache Version Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8

Comment: @Ryan, I recognize that the error he is getting is not usually associated with bad input.  But including bad input in your answer muddies the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime::createFromFormat()`  is most useful when you have a date string in an unconventional format. You create a date object by giving the format of your weird date string so that it knows how to parse it.  Like so:

```
$datestring= '2012-06-11 23:59:59';
$mydate= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datestring);
echo $mydate->format('Y/m/d');
```

In your case, the date string is a standard format.  So you can create your date like this:

```
$mydate= new DateTime($datestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the procedural (non OOP) style

```
$t = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', '2012-06-11 23:59:59');
```

work for you?

Comment: if you run this, you'll see that `$t` is not a DateTime object. It is a boolean FALSE. That's because the format must match that of the date string.

Comment: Actually i want to use DateTime...

Answer (score 0):

Yeap i was right...eclipse issue:
When i did phpinfo from debug mode i found out that it was running as PHP 5.2,
changed the project setting and presto! all function are there!

Thanks everyone for the great input!! as always pleasure asking questions in stackoverflow :)